# Extracting information while keeping relations with Xpath

Tags: xpath

I have a html/xml file which is structured like this:

```
<a class="my-class">
  <b>Text1</b>
  <c>
    <d>123</d>
    <d>456</d>
  </c>
  <b>Text2</b>
  <c>
    <d>789</d>
    <d>000</d>
  </c>
</a
```

I am searching for a xPath expression that can give me the output like this (in any kind of list):

```
Text1.123
Text1.456
Text2.789
Text2.000
```

I played and tested around with concat() but I couldn't figure out, how to extract those information and somehow keep their relation by using only one xPath expression.
Is that even possible?

Comment: `Text1.789
Text1.000 `should those be `Text2.789
Text2.000`?

Comment: sorry typo, text is now correct

Comment: we can achieve this if you are OK to `executeJavaScript` which will return the expected output as a string. Let me know if you are good to use `executeJavaScript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only achievable with **XPath-2.0 or above**.
So the following XPath-2.0 expression will achieve what you want:

```
for $c in /a/c return for $i in $c/d return concat($c/preceding-sibling::b[1],'.',$i,'&#xa;')
```

**Its output is:**

```
Text1.123
Text1.456
Text2.789
Text2.000
```

There may be some leading spaces, but this depends on the XPath processor..

Comment: Right now I'm using HtmlUnit to further use the elements found with by the Xpath expressions. Because your suggested answer isn't working, even though it looks like it makes a lot of sense, I guess that HtmlUnit only supports XPath1. Are you absolutely sure there is no way to gather the needed information with XPath1? 
Or else, can you recommend an XPath processor (for java) that I might use?

Comment: I don't know about HtmlUnit, but if you can implement the for-loops there, XPath-1.0 is sufficient. Simply loop over all `d` elements with `/a/c/d` and then retrieve the corresponding `Text...` elements with `preceding-sibling::b[1]` relative to the current element.